# How does mount determine the default mounting options for newly attached filesystems?

Tags: filesystems, mount

Things grow tedious quickly when playing with a massive tool like `mount`. With different filesystem types and different settings for each filesystem, `mount` stood the test of time. I wonder how `mount` knows which default settings when mounting a filesystem. Aside from the fact the `udisksd` daemon automatically mounts fielsystems, how does `mount` determine the appropriate settings when mounting a filesystem without options like the following:

```
# mount /dev/sdc /media/usb_drive
```

What we're particularly interested at is the *long options* of `mount` such as (`ro`, `rw`, `noexec`, `exec`, `nodev`,...). As seen above, the command doesn't list any long options:

```
$ mount | grep /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc on /media/usb_drive type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

You can see some options were used by default for the ext4 filesystem when mounting /dev/sdc: `(rw,relatime,data=ordered)`. Though, there's no entry for /dev/sdc in fstab. Notice that the filesystem lives on the whole usb drive not on a partition. The above command looks like as if we ran this command:

```
# mount /dev/sdc /media/usb_drive -o rw,relatime,data=ordered
```

What is the mechanism that `mount` uses to determine the appropriate default mounting options?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Linux at least, any defaults are either hard coded into:

1. The `mount` command itself
2. The filesystem specific mount helper (`mount.ext4` in this case).
3. The generic VFS layer `mount` function in the kernel
4. The filesystem specific `mount` function in the kernel

`relatime` falls under case 3, and is actually a common location for people to locally patch in custom kernels (usually it gets patched to default to `noatime`).  `rw` is also case 3, but it can be overridden by the FS specific `mount` function in the kernel.

`data=ordered` is from 4, is ext* specific, and can be changed at build time to `data=writeback` if you're building your own kernel (and may be different on some distros).

The exact list you get for default options will vary by filesystem type (BTRFS has a different set other than `rw,relatime` than ext4 for example), by specifics of the filesystem (you can embed some default options in the superblock for ext4), and sometimes even by hardware (BTRFS tries to guess if you have an SSD and will add the FS specific `ssd` mount option if it thinks you do).

The situation is pretty similar on most other systems as well, although on some older UNIX systems `mount` ends up just being a multiplexer for FS specific mount commands.

Comment: data=ordered default comes from the kernel (where it can be changed at build time): https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext3_Data%3DOrdered_vs_Data%3DWriteback_mode

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I completely forgot about it.  I've updated my answer with that info.

Answer (score 3):

This is from the `mount(8)` manual on an Ubuntu system:

> FILESYSTEM-INDEPENDENT MOUNT OPTIONS
>
> Some of these options are only useful when they appear in the `/etc/fstab` file.
>
> **Some  of  these  options  could be enabled or disabled by default in the system kernel.  To check the current setting see the options in `/proc/mounts`.**  Note
>          that filesystems also have per-filesystem specific default mount options (see for example `tune2fs -l` output for `extN` filesystems).

The equivalent manual on e.g. OpenBSD makes it clear that the options listed in the manual are for setting non-default mount options. So there's a `softdep` and an `noatime` option since `nosoftdep` and `atime` is the default, for example.

Comment: Coincidentally I came across that paragraph just now. Could you clarify the last sentence in you answer?